# does google play generate patches automatically

Tags: android, google-play, patch

This may be the biggest noob question. plz dont mind.

My question is for example we uploaded a big app to google play lets say 500mb. then we found a minor bug in the app and fixed it. Now when i update it(i update the full app because i don't know how to generate patches) on my google play console, does it generate automatic patch for that minor bug or does it make the users download whole app again??

also what is the status of amazon app store for same problem???

BTW, the app will be made using unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you [Integrate the Play Asset Delivery Library](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#java-kotlin-asset-delivery), then Google Play will auto-update your game assets with advanced compression and delta patching.

And this available for [unity too](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/play-asset-delivery.html)

[Amazon are working on supporting these features](https://developer.amazon.com/apps-and-games/blogs/2021/07/appstore-support-for-android-app-bundle)

> **Will my apps get all available App Bundle benefits?**
>
> We currently support upload of apps in App Bundle format. We are working to enable customer experience benefits for App Bundles incrementally over time, such as app size reduction, `dynamic delivery`, or instant app support.

Comment: does this feature also come for unity for windows release....

Comment: @PriyanshYadav  Yes

Comment: can you plz help me i cant find it... during android build there's option of incremental build but for windows build there is no such option... also i recently looked into asset bundles but then found they cant import executable code...